# Классы JS, переопределение toString

Tags: javascript

Создать класс `Programmer`, инстанс которого обладает полями `name`, `stack` (массив строк, типа `["Python", "PHP", "Java"]`), и методом `code()` (который перебирает массив `stack` и выводит сообщения вида "Oleg is coding on Python", "Oleg is coding on PHP", "Oleg is coding on Java"). Метод `code()` должен храниться в прототипе класса. Переопределить метод `toString()` у инстансов `Programmer`, чтобы они выводили сообщение вида "Hello my name is Oleg".

У меня ошибка что `toString()` undefined. И я не понимаю, как объявить `stack` массив `["Python", "PHP", "Java"]`, чтобы он его перебрал и выводил строку на каждый `stack`.

```js
class Programmer {
    constructor(userName, stack){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.stack = stack;
    Programmer.prototype.code = function () {
        console.log(`${this.userName} is coding on ${this.stack}`);
    };
}}

const pr =new Programmer('Oleg', ['Python', 'PHP', 'Java']);
pr.code();

pr.prototype.toString = function prToString() {
    return `Hello my name is ${this.userName} `;
}
```

"Oleg is coding on Python,PHP,Java" - вот как у меня выдает, всё вместе.

Comment: `this.name` - такого поля не существует.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Но всё равно ошибка

Comment: У `pr` нет свойства `prototype`, это инстанция.

Comment: Зачем вы мешаете классовый стиль и прототипный стиль?

Comment: Этого условие требует, разве нет?

Comment: Ну можно просто переопределить метод `toString` внутри класса и вроде как всё... Все его инстансы будут выполнять `toString` так как вы переопределите

Comment: Да спасибо, я уже понял это)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо поменять `pr.prototype` на `Object.getPrototypeOf(pr)`

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(pr).toString = function prToString() {
    return `Hello my name is ${this.userName} `;
}
```

> У меня ошибка что toString udefined. И я не понимаю, как объявить stack массив [«Python», «PHP», «Java»], чтобы он его перебрал и выводил строку на каждый stack

```
Programmer.prototype.code = function() {
    this.stack.map(e => console.log(`${this.userName} is coding on ${e}`))
}
```

Comment: Почему вы используете метод `map`?

Comment: `__proto__` deprecated свойство, его не используют. Почитайте [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Comment: Забыл что `__proto__` уже убрали...

Comment: А что насчёт `map`, почему вы используете его? Разве не будет логичнее использовать `forEach`, который и предназначен для таких операций?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(pr)` - а в чём проблема напрямую обращаться к прототипу, у нас ведь есть прямой доступ к нему?

Comment: А как к нему напрямую обратиться и вызвать его?

Comment: Ну раз уж у вас есть ответ и вы даже никак не старались, то тогда я уж лучше прямо напишу, вот так: `Programmer.prototype`. Я про "вызвать" я не совсем понял, прототипы нельзя "вызывать", к ним можно обращаться. Если же вы про метод `toString`, то тогда это нужно делать в инстанции (инстансе).

Comment: Да, сглупил немного. То есть метод toString надо поместить внутрь класса. И уже потом к нему обращаться.

Comment: NNL993, в задаче стоит прописать `toString` к инстансу, а не к родительскому классу, по поводу `map` абсолютно согласен что нужно использовать `forEach`, остатки профДеградации)))

Answer (score 1):

Я бы просто создал класс с полями `name` и `stack` и методами `code` и `toString`:

```js
class Programmer {
  name = null;
  stack = null;
  
  constructor(name, stack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stack = stack;
  }
  
  code() {
    for(const programmingLanguage of this.stack) {
      console.log(`${this.name} is coding on ${programmingLanguage}`);
    }
  }
  
  toString() {
    console.log(`Hello my name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

const programmer = new Programmer('Oleg', ['JavaScript', 'Java', 'PHP']);

programmer.code();
programmer.toString();
'' + programmer; // Вызывает метод toString автоматически

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(programmer).code);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(programmer).toString);
```